# How to configure Spring Mvc Configuration Error

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, configuration

I´m updating my project from spring 2.5 to 5 with MVC configuration
I try to make java based config with some problems this is my code:

Web.xml

```
<web-app 
xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
version="3.0">

<display-name>Publisher Portal</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        com.netsol.publisher.config.AppConfig
    </param-value> 
</context-param>

<context-param>
     <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>/WEB-INF/log4j.properties</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jRefreshInterval</param-name>
    <param-value>1000</param-value>
</context-param>    

<listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>publisher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
          <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
          <param-value>
              org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
          </param-value>
      </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.netsol.publisher.config.SpringWebMvcConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <description>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</description>    
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>publisher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

my AppConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(excludeFilters=@Filter(org.springframework.stereotype.Controller.class)})
public class AppConfig {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppConfig.class);
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
}
```

And my SpringWebMvcConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.netsol.publisher.controller" })
public class SpringWebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private static final int CACHE_PERIOD = 31556926; // one year

    @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        registry.jsp("/WEB-INF/jsp/", ".jsp");
    }   

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        //this will map uri to jsp view directly without a controller
        registry.addViewController("/hi").setViewName("hello");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home.do");
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        // Serving static files using the Servlet container's default Servlet.
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry formatterRegistry) {
        // add your custom formatters
    }



    @Bean
    PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer getPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        ppc.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("publisher-portal.properties"));
        ppc.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return ppc;
    }


  @Bean
  public SimpleUrlHandlerMapping simpleUrlHandlerMapping () {
      SimpleUrlHandlerMapping mapping = new SimpleUrlHandlerMapping();
      mapping.setOrder(Integer.MAX_VALUE - 2);

      Properties urlProperties = new Properties();
      urlProperties.put("/home", "LoginController");

      mapping.setMappings(urlProperties);
      return mapping;
  }

}
```

My controllers:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/home")
public class LoginController extends BaseController {

    static final String sccsId = "%TC-INFO%";

    @Autowired
    private PublisherFacade publisherFacade; 

    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(LoginController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index.do", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
    public ModelAndView showLoginPage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
        return getLoginView(request, Constants.USER_LOGIN_PAGE);
    }
```

The problem is that

```
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'publisher'
- FrameworkServlet 'publisher': initialization started
- Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'publisher-servlet': startup date [Wed Sep 19 16:12:08 ART 2018]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
- No annotated classes found for specified class/package [com.netsol.publisher.config.SpringWebMvcConfig]
- JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
- Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'publisher-servlet': startup date [Wed Sep 19 16:12:08 ART 2018]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
- FrameworkServlet 'publisher': initialization completed in 1146 ms
sep 19, 2018 4:12:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet [PendingOrderCheckerServlet] as unavailable
sep 19, 2018 4:12:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [PendingOrderCheckerServlet] in web application [/publisher-portal] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.netsol.publisher.batch.PendingOrderCheckerServlet
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1309)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:527)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1044)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4978)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5290)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1420)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1410)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

sep 19, 2018 4:12:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
sep 19, 2018 4:12:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
sep 19, 2018 4:12:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 31382 ms
- No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/publisher-portal/home/index.do] in DispatcherServlet with name 'publisher'
- No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/publisher-portal/home/index.do] in DispatcherServlet with name 'publisher'
```

I want to know if my configuration its ok and why I cannot found the mappings of my controllers

Comment: Your mapping of PendingOrderCheckerServlet does not appear in the web.xml. There is something wrong with this esrvlet.

Comment: in my web.xml I have this for that  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>PendingOrderCheckerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.netsol.publisher.batch.PendingOrderCheckerServlet</servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

Comment: The main problem is when I run my app I cannot navegate and got Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server. and on console I have - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/publisher-portal/home/index.do] in DispatcherServlet with name 'publisher'